# How to select a different Metamask address when using Uniswap?

Tags: metamask, addresses, uniswap, hardware-wallets

I want to use Uniswap with my hardware wallet. So I go into my Metamask wallet, connect to my hardware wallet, I see my coin balance, then I open Uniswap. The trouble is that Uniswap is showing an empty address for my Metamask wallet instead of the hardware wallet address with my coin balance. How may I get Uniswap to look instead at the hardware wallet address that I connected to Metamask, please?

Comment: Before this gets closed by community, please ask https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us and post the answer yourself here :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want Uniswap to use another address from Metamask, you have to connect it to Uniswap website.

1. In Metamask, select the address you want to use (in that case, the hardware wallet that you linked with Metamask).
2. Go to the Uniswap app website on your browser.
3. In Metamask, just to the left of the name of you hardware address, you should see "Not connected". Click on "Not connected" and you will be prompted to connect this address to Uniswap.
4. Voila! The "Not Connected" button should now show "Connected". If it does not work, try refreshing the Uniswap website and do it again. Lock/Unlock Metamask also.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

So you need to disconnect the first account link to metamask then exit uniswap and login again to uniswap and link the second account.